# ora-01403 no data found error,ora-04088 error during execution of trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I have this trigger

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_cust
after insert or update on nbty_customer
referencing old as old new as new
for each row
declare
pragma autonomous_transaction;
V_REQ VARCHAR2(10);
begin 

 IF(:NEW.cust_sal<1000)
        THEN
        select :NEW.cust_sal+:OLD.cust_sal INTO V_REQ FROM nbty_customer
        where cust_id=:old.cust_id;

    ELSE
    SELECT :NEW.cust_sal-:OLD.cust_sal INTO V_REQ FROM nbty_customer where cust_id=:old.cust_id;
    end if;

merge into nbty_cache_cust 
    using
       (select distinct :new.cust_id cust_id, :new.cust_name cust_name,V_REQ V_REQ
       from nbty_customer) b
       on (cust_nbty_id = b.cust_id)
        when matched then
       update set cust_nbty_name = b.cust_name, cust_nbty_sal = b.V_REQ 
       when not matched then
      insert (cust_nbty_id, cust_nbty_name, cust_nbty_sal)
      values (b.cust_id, b.cust_name, b.V_REQ);
      commit;
      end;
```

Which compiles properly but when an insertion is done on the table nbty_customer like for example

```
insert into nbty_customer values('2','abc','200')
```

It throws ora-01403 no data found error,ora-04088 error during execution of trigger
Kindly help, I am not able to figure out what the issue is?

Comment: We can't tell without the data. The fact is, there is a `select` out there yielding no results, which you don't catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was due to a `select into` clause which returned a 'no data found' so I removed the `select into` and directly used a bind variable instead:

```
IF(:new.cust_sal<1000)
then
  v_req:=nvl(:new.cust_sal,0)+nvl(:old.cust_sal,0);
else
  v_req:=nvl(:new.cust_sal,0)-nvl(:old.cust_sal,0);
end if;
```

This solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just commented, and then I noticed this:

```
select :NEW.cust_sal+:OLD.cust_sal INTO V_REQ FROM nbty_customer
    where cust_id=:old.cust_id;
```

On `insert`, this `select` will fail since there is no `:old.cust_id`. Use `:new.cust_id` instead. (also, `:old.cust_sal` will be null too)

Comment: ya i used :new.cust_id still its throwing the same error,sorry for replying so late

Comment: I tried using                                                    select nvl(:NEW.cust_sal,0)+nvl(:OLD.cust_sal,0) INTO V_REQ FROM nbty_customer  where cust_id=:new.cust_id;                                  but to no avail its still throwing the same error,please help

Comment: Can you add a full insert statement in your question, including column names?

Comment: insert into nbty_customer(cust_id,cust_name,cust_sal) values ('111','abc,'1000');

Comment: This will go in your else branche which is invalid. There isn't a customer yet then.

Comment: i used   IF(:NEW.cust_sal<1000)
       THEN
        select nvl(:NEW.cust_sal,0)+nvl(:OLD.cust_sal,0) INTO V_REQ FROM nbty_customer
        where cust_id=:new.cust_id;
       ELSE
       SELECT nvl(:NEW.cust_sal,0)-nvl(:OLD.cust_sal,0) INTO V_REQ FROM nbty_customer where cust_id=:new.cust_id;
      end if;
       exception when no_data_found then V_REQ:=:NEW.CUST_SAL;       now this is going into exception always and just returns the new value,really need a solution for this..

Comment: @saniyamapari: Did you include changes in your code that Frank suggested you? Also, include more information so we can reproduce the problem. Include a table schema in your question.

Comment: THE problem was due to a select into clause which returned a no data found so i removed the select into and directly used a bind variable instead                                                                  IF(:new.cust_sal<1000)
        then
          v_req:=nvl(:new.cust_sal,0)+nvl(:old.cust_sal,0);
         else
          v_req:=nvl(:new.cust_sal,0)-nvl(:old.cust_sal,0);
          end if;                                                             which solved the problem  :)

Comment: ya actually it is not allowing me to select an answer.. stack overflow is giving a warning that i can't select my own answer to be correct before five hours... :(

Answer (score 0):

In your trigger body, you're trying to select the data of your new row:

```
 SELECT :NEW.cust_sal-:OLD.cust_sal INTO V_REQ FROM nbty_customer where cust_id=:old.cust_id;
```

But you declared your trigger body as `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION`. Therefore, your trigger does not see the changes that triggered the trigger execution in the first place.

Using `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` in triggers is *never* a good idea; see [Tom Kyte on Triggers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html) for a detailed explanation on why you want to avoid this.

If you need to cache your data for performance reasons, I'd recommend using a Materialized View instead. You can set it to `REFRESH ON COMMIT` if needed:

```
create materialized view mv_cache
refresh on commit 
as 
select distinct cust_id cust_id, cust_name cust_name, V_REQ 
from nbty_customer
```